# Error when creating too many playlists?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

I used the YouTube API but a new error appears recently when creating playlist:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.playlist",
    "reason": "exceededRateLimit",
    "message": "The user has created too many playlists recently. Please try the request again later."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The user has created too many playlists recently. Please try the request again later."
 }
}
```

I got this message by creating 10 playlists in 10 minutes. 
After some searches it seems this message show up after 10 playlists created; no relation with timeframe like in 10 seconds or in 10 minutes or more.

Can we have more details about this new error ? Maybe have timeframe information ? A retry-after header ? Something ?

Thank you.

Google Issue Tracker here => https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79222309

Comment: Same problem for me. It was for testing purpose as the API does not provide a sandbox to test our code.

Comment: Same issue here.  I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: Maybe it's because YouTube Music is coming, that will probably make a change in the YouTube API like this one...

Comment: Documentation is missing. Seems to be there's a limit of 10 playlists every 24 hours or so right now - that's simply unacceptable o.o

Comment: Issue closed as WAI, no documentation, YouTube couldn't care less, as usual.

Comment: First not possible to do monetization through API, now this.. why YouTube.. why..

Answer (score -2):

Youtube API v3 have a limit based on "units"

> Daily quota: 1 000 000 units.
>
> *Please, keep in mind that when you perform insert and update operations, they write data and so also return a resource. **So the
>   operation of inserting a playlist requires a quota of 50 units for the
>   write operation, and the cost of the returned playlist resource.**

Here's a handy quota calulator: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

Source: https://elfsight.com/blog/2017/06/youtube-data-api-v3-limits-operations-resources-methods-etc/

Comment: Not a limit based on quota here. Create a new  API key and only do 10 playlists creation and you will get this error.